# Calling a function from highcharts upon clicking the piechart

Tags: php, highcharts

I would like to call a function when someone clicks on the pie-chart which I built using Highchart.

My pie chart code is:

```
function open_risk_level_pie()
{
    $chart = new Highchart();

    $chart->chart->renderTo = "open_risk_level_pie";
    $chart->chart->plotBackgroundColor = lightblue;
    $chart->chart->plotBorderWidth = null;
    $chart->chart->plotShadow = false;
    $chart->title->text = "Risk Level";

    $chart->tooltip->formatter = new HighchartJsExpr("function() {
    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.point.y; }");

    $chart->plotOptions->pie->allowPointSelect = 1;
    $chart->plotOptions->pie->cursor = "pointer";
    $chart->plotOptions->pie->dataLabels->enabled = false;
    $chart->plotOptions->pie->showInLegend = 1;
$chart->plotOptions->pie->colors = array('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'black');
    $chart->credits->enabled = false;

    $array = //some db access code
$high = $array[0][0];
$medium = $array[1][0];
$low = $array[2][0];

    // If the array is empty
    if (empty($array))
    {
            $data[] = array("No Data Available", 0);
    }
    // Otherwise
    else
    {
            // Create the data array
            foreach ($array as $row)
            {
                    $data[] = array($row['level'], (int)$row['num']);
            }

            $chart->series[] = array('type' => "pie",
                    'name' => "Level",
                    'data' => $data);
    }

echo "<div id=\"open_risk_level_pie\"></div>\n";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
echo $chart->render("open_risk_level_pie");
echo "</script>\n";
}
```

Now I want to call a function whenever someone clicks on the pie chart. I have searched a lot, but unable to find. Some sites mentioned to use "formatter", but I failed to use it. If formatter is the solution for my question please give me steps for the above code.

Answer (score 2):

Use an on click event for a slice.

[Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events.click).

Comment: Quality of this answer is poor, but is very correct.

Comment: Thanks, please approve my answer. I was in a hurry to catch the bus, and that was the only thing I could think of :)

Comment: @PawełFus can you please just elaborate your answer, I don't know exactly how to use the on click event, I tried alot but its not working.
Thank You

Comment: Use it the way described in docs, also there you can see jsFiddle demo with code. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with PHP, so I won't be able to help more.